# How to get value from resolved defer Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i am creating android application using ionic and angularjs and using window.requestFileSystem for get image from storage. So for this process i used `$q.defer()` for asynchronous process and its working fine and showing object in console: `console.log(deferred.promise)`

[image]

but now, when i am trying to get the value from `deferred.promise` like

```
var vals = deferred.promise;
console.log(vals.$$state.value);
```

its showing `undefined`. Can anyone tell me how i can get that value?

My Code:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
            imagePath = fileSystem.root.toURL() + 'SmaartMedia/' + splited[splitedLength-1];
            deferred.resolve(imagePath);
            $rootScope.$apply();
        });
    }, false);
    var vals = deferred.promise;
    console.log(vals.$$state.value);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getStuff() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
      imagePath = fileSystem.root.toURL() + 'SmaartMedia/' + splited[splitedLength - 1];
      deferred.resolve(imagePath);
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  }, false);
  return deferred.promise;
}

//Get value like this
getStuff().then(function(response){
  //Use value here
});
```

Comment: Not correct, look at the eventListener. defer should be inside. And i also don't think it's really working, because the eventListener will not be executed in this function, it only get registered. Nothing more. So the return won't work either. There is no nice way to achieve his goal, because of the eventListener.